# Why does Android studio reinstalls everytime I open it?

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

Whenever I open the Android studio it asks for install. I had updated the studio but all of it is washed out the next time I open it. I have to update every time I want to use

Comment: Which operating system and Android Studio version you are using?

Comment: You have not installed Android Studio Properly. Follow https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxdSHBhCdARIsAG6zhlWSCqZ2DBo_6eedQ2aAsxf7wol3YO9ES5flif4ixLk10j7elGIOTH8aApHwEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds